# How can I inject member annotations into my current instantiated object using Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, guice

I am trying to inject a custom annotation using the Guice `bindInterceptor` into my currently instantiated Service.java class.  Unfortunately when I call `myMethod()` the `OnAnnotationEvent::invoke` method is not called. How can I use Guice to call `OnAnnotationEvent::invoke` when the `@OnAnnotation` annotation tag is used on a method in the current class?

My code looks like this:

**Service.java**

```
//Instantiated by another service
public class Service extends AbstractVerticle {
  private DataAccess dataAccess;

  @Inject
  public void setDataAccess(DataAccess dataAccess){
    this.dataAccess = dataAccess;
  }

  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {
    Guice.createInjector(new DataAccessModule()).injectMembers(this);
    myMethod();
  } 

  @MyAnnotation
  public void myMethod() {
    dataAccess.doStuff();
  }
}
```

**DataAccessModule.java**

```
public class DataAccessModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    OnAnnotationEvent onAnnotationEvent = new OnAnnotationEvent();
    bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class), onAnnotationEvent);
    bind(DataAcess.class).to(DataAccessImpl.class);
  }
}
```

**OnAnnotationEvent**

```
public class OnAnnotationEvent implements MethodInterceptor {
  @Override
  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Annotation called on: " + invocation.getMethod().getName();

    return invocation.proceed();
  }
}
```

**MyAnnotation**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you creating new injector that does not knows anything about your class. If you just need injector in your class - use `@Inject private Injector injector;`. If you need to load some aditional modules locally you just need to create child injector :

```
@Inject private baseInjector;
...
injector = baseInjector.createChildInjector(new Module1(),new Moddule2());
```

Comment: injectMembers(this); should inject all my dependencies in locally right?

Comment: basicaly to do "method interception" you need to have some kind of "proxy" class that handles interception. so if you are trying to inject method call interceptor you could not do it on existing object.

Comment: I'm not even sure that if you will build child injector that contains definition of method interceptor it will really work, because your object is already constructed and i have no idea how to make method interceptor work.
"method interception" is different from "dependency injection"

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because your Service instance isn't managed by Guice. To make it work you must either create Service with Guice or annotate method doStuff in DataAccessImpl with MyAnnotation.